# SQL Update in another class

Tags: java, sql, class, methods

Thanks for helping me out with my problem.
So I tried to insert a SQL Update using a method in a class named Functions, the main program doesn't give any error, and whenever I use the function, it just don't change anything in the SQL table after refreshing.

Here is my updateSQL method in class Functions :

```
public static void updateSQL(String sql, String updatenames[]) 
{
    Connection connected = null;
    PreparedStatement prepared = null;
    connected = connexionmysql.connexionDB();
    try 
    {
        prepared = connected.prepareStatement(sql);
        for(int i = 1; i < updatenames.length+1 ; i++) {
            prepared.setString(i, updatenames[i-1]);
        }
        prepared.execute();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here is how I call this function in my main class :

```
String datan[] = { inputPASS, type1, inputEMAIL, inputNAME };
                    Functions.updateSQL("UPDATE users SET userPASS = ? ,userTYPE = ? ,userEMAIL = ? WHERE userNAME = ? ", datan);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem. The functions I did write are working as expected, but the problem was in the way I was calling the method.

Instead of calling the function in a static way, I was calling it in an "usual" way so Eclipse didn't give me any error in that line.